# Tensorflow not recognized even though it is installed

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, anaconda, gpu

I am trying to run spot-rna on my windows pc. The computer is absolutely brand new and was opened today.
I have installed python 3.6 and anaconda3. I also installed tensorflow in a virtual environment.
Basically, I followed the installation steps (for gpu) given here: https://github.com/jaswindersingh2/SPOT-RNA

This is what the path for my user looks like:

[image]

This is what my system variables path looks like:

[image]

However, when I try to run the test command, it does not recognize tensorflow

[image]

I also updated tensorflow to 2.4.1 with pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow. When I run the test command again in the command prompt, I still get the same problem where it says no module named 'tensorflow'. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Update:

I deleted everything (including anaconda and python). Then I installed python 3.9.4 (latest at this time). In a command prompt, I wrote the following commands:

`pip install virtualenv`

`c:\users\ankit\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I then created a folder called VirtualEnvironments in c:\users\ankit, in which I created my virtual environment called venv and activated it with these commands:

`virtualenv -p python3.9.4 venv`

`.\venv\Scripts\activate`

I then installed tenserflow 2.5.0 (latest version) with `pip install tensorflow`

Then, in the same folder (VirtualEnvironments), I installed SPOT-RNA:

`git clone https://github.com/jaswindersingh2/SPOT-RNA.git`

`cd SPOT-RNA`

`wget "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsrcf460nbjqpxa/SPOT-RNA-models.tar.gz" || wget -O SPOT-RNA-models.tar.gz "https://app.nihaocloud.com/f/fbf3315a91d542c0bdc2/?dl=1"`

`tar -xvzf SPOT-RNA-models.tar.gz && del SPOT-RNA-models.tar.gz`

In the VirtualEnvironment path (C:\Users\ankit\VirtualEnvironments), I installed pandas, numpy and tqdm. I then went into SPOT-RNA and ran the command
`py SPOT-RNA.py  --inputs sample_inputs/batch_seq.fasta  --outputs 'outputs/' --gpu 0` again. It resolved the initial problem of tenserflow not being recognized, but there still seems to be issues with tenserflow/cuda and some libraries. Am I missing a download somewhere? The documentation seems to say I don't need install CUDA and cuDNN if I use the gpu.

[image]

Comment: are you sure your venv was active when you installed `tensorflow`? It's also possible you have multiple instances of python. Microsoft tries to push it's own distribution via the windows store which may be caught first because `...\WindowsApps\ ` is first on your `PATH`

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure the venv was activated when I installed tensorflow (using conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0). As for the mutiple instances, I just restarted my computer and used the command prompt to try again, and I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: did you tried it using anaconda prompt?

Comment: I do sometimes have success with `conda`, but `pip` is really the standard, and is how tensorflow.org tells you how to install. For newer releases (past 1.15) all you need is `pip install tensorflow` (even for gpu support). If you really need the older version, it's still pretty simple, but `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` are separate and both are needed (`pip install tensorflow==1.14` `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14`).

Comment: @Luiz Anaconda prompt gives the same message

Comment: @Aaron So you suggest I uninstall tenserflow and start over the installation but instead of using conda, I do the steps given in https://github.com/jaswindersingh2/SPOT-RNA for virtualenv. And when I install tenserflow, instead of using `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0`, I simply use `pip install tenserflow`?

Comment: starting from nothing: 1. create and activate venv (regular venv not conda env). 2. `pip install tensorflow==1.14` 3. `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14` 4. install SPOT-RNA

Comment: `tensorflow-gpu` is an addon to `tensorflow`, and both are needed if you want to use cuda. for versions after 1.15, the two were merged so all you need is `tensorflow`

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#older_versions_of_tensorflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231881/discussion-between-aaron-and-ankit).

Comment: Are you using/trying to use Conda for this?

Comment: Could you please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install tensorflow in your system. Sorry for the late response.